# My computer wont Shutdown?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, shutdown

Okay... So I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Upgraded from 12.04.3 ) I've been using Ubuntu for about two years now and I know myself around the system pretty well...

Every time I attempt to shut down the computer I always get stuck on the Ubuntu Splash menu and have to push the button to shut it off.

Specs:

- 6GB ram
- Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7400 @ 2.80 GHz x2G
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV635
- 64bit OS Ubuntu 14.04
- 1TB hard drive (Dual booted Windows 7 on 600GB partition)

Comment: @DavidFoerster This isn't a duplicate of that question (it is probably a duplicate of something else though). The two questions describe completely different events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you but there is a terminal command for shutting down your computer.

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

You have to be root to do so, that's why the sudo. shutdown is the command you would like to preform, -P is the option in shutdown to power off once it's complete, and now states that you would like to shutdown the computer now. I hope this helps you a little. I am like you and know  a little about ubuntu but I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem a lot on my AMD A8 processor with ATI Radeon graphics.

Fortunately for me,a simple workaround,works well(like 9 out of 10 times).

Ensure that the laptop is plugged(i.e., it is connected to a power source) whenever you are shutting down the system.Some system resources might not be getting enough power required to complete its task.

Comment: While your workaround is valid, I doubt that lack of power is the reason for the inability to shut down a system. It's most likely a faulty driver or system configuration that only trips in case of battery power.